# Can I use two Google Analytics id's in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I've seen questions regarding websites but haven't been able to find any info regarding the possibility of this within native mobile applications for iOS.

Would like to maintain my own analytics and then also allow the various clients who's pages are displayed to also see analytics tracked on their own account by including both account id's inside the app somehow.

Anyone done this or have somewhere they can point me for more information?

Comment: Like multilpe tracking IDs? (UA-XXXX-1 and UA-XXXX-2)

Comment: Yes, exactly like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use multiple tracking IDs. From [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/53459/google-analytics-ios) page:

[image]

Comment: From the above it's not clear how to send analytics data to both trackers which is what I'm looking to do.  It looks like I can switch which tracker the data is being sent to by changing the default but I'd like to send the same data to both for the entire app.

Comment: In that case, you would switch to tracker 1, send the data. Then, switch to tracker 2 and send the same data. So, you would have to send the data each time for each seperate tracking ID. You could create a seperate class with a function in it setup to send the data to all your tracking IDs, then reference that class+function in the rest of your project. There is no way (currently) to send the data one time and have it associate with multiple IDs at once.